# vwdial Bad init string on RPI

Tags: raspberry-pi, 3g, wvdial, huawei

I'm trying to get a Huawei E398 3G USB modem to work on my Raspberry Pi 3
When I run `wvdial` I get the following response:

```
pi@mypi:~ $ sudo wvdial
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
ERROR
--> Bad init string.
```

This is my wvdial.conf:

```
pi@mypi:~ $ cat /etc/wvdial.conf
[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
Modem Type = USB Modem
ISDN = 0
New PPPD = yes
Stupid Mode = yes
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
Phone = *99#
Username = internet
Password = internet
Baud = 115200
```

Anyone have any clue on what could cause this? I've tried every other init string I could come across, but every single one gives me the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are using the correct APN.
My company's SIM cards used a special APN; once I added the correct one it worked perfectly.

`Init3 = AT +CGDCONT=1,"IP","<company APN>"`